# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named lms

Tags: python

```
>>>import adaptfilt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import adaptfilt
  File "C:\Users\walid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\adaptfilt\__init__.py", line 41
    print '   LMS: ', lmsres
                   ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I have fixed this erreur I edit the file `__init__.py` but it show me again :

```
>>>import adaptfilt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import adaptfilt
  File "C:\Users\walid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\adaptfilt\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lms import lms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lms'
```

Comment: it looks like you installed a module designed for python 2 into python 3. You could try running it through the `2to3` tool but it can't guarantee to auto fix everything in the package.

Comment: The library you use is designed with incompatible syntax for python3, you should use python2

Answer (score 2):

You can try running python's 2to3 tool on the package to see if it can just fix all the syntaxes but it isn't guarenteed to find every incompatibility.

So you'd run this in cmd:

```
2to3  "C:\Users\walid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\adaptfilt\" -w
```

the `-w` at the end just tells it to override the files already there, if you get an error saying `2to3` isn't a command you can try:

```
python -m lib2to3 "<PATH>" -w
```

Or if `python` isn't a command use `py`... there is unfortunately not very standardized naming for the python command across platforms.